# Turn on display of blackberry device in locked mode

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I want to display some alert on display and for that i wish to turn on the display if its off , usually when BB is locked, is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application will need to request, and be granted `PERMISSION_DISPLAY_LOCKED` (from the class `ApplicationPermissions`) which is available starting in OS 5.0